# inserting records in a sqlite database does not change its size but

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with about 100 records inserted in it. the size of the file on my disk is about 65 KB. It was the same before and after the insertion of data. I compressed the file to `.tar.7z` format. As I keep adding data the size of the database file stays the same but when I compress it I see the size of archive file growing. Why is that so? Could someone please explain the reason for this behavior I am observing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- SQLite organises data into "pages"
- In short, pages are blocks of storage on-disk; it doesn't just write one piece of data to disk, it writes a whole page
- SQLite creates/allocated a page, then fills it up as you write to it
- ... So that explains the 65k; because sqlite creates pages that are blank, and is filling them with data as you add data
- As for 7z: "blank" is super compressible.
- Twenty thousand zeros is trivially compressible as the string "twenty thousand zeros", and 7zip is *way* more efficient than me writing English
- Wheras as soon as you make it "a thousand zeros, followed by five, six, nine, twelve, three thousand and one, and another thousand zeros"... way less efficient to compress